# Didn't change the color of container

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the color of the `Container` when it is pressed and go to the new screen but when I come back the color must have changed.

```
 class FreelancerLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const FreelancerLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FreelancerLayout> createState() => _FreelancerLayoutState();
}

class _FreelancerLayoutState extends State<FreelancerLayout>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<FreelancerLayout> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: catList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
                child: GridCategory(
                    category: catList[index],
                    press: () {
                     
                      pushNewScreen(context,
                          screen: CategoryPage(category: catList[index]));
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**GridCategory.dart**

```
class GridCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  final Category category;
  final VoidCallback? press;

  const GridCategory({
    Key? key,
    required this.category,
    this.press,
    // required this.selectedIcon,
    // required this.unSelectedIcon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GridCategory> createState() => _GridCategoryState();
}

class _GridCategoryState extends State<GridCategory> {
  final bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.press,
      child: Container(
        width: 110,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isSelected ? AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor : Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Image.asset(widget.category.catImage!)),
            Text(
              widget.category.iconName!,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't see any method to change `isSelected` here, soo it value alway `false`. Second, `isSelected` is `final` make it value can't changes, remove `final`. Thirt, because `isSelected` is local props, it changes will no appear in other page, you need to passing `selected` from parent if you want it.

***Update***: In case you want highlight selected category when selected and change it when select other cate? You need create a variable call 'selectedIndex' to store the selected category index, handle changes it everytime u tap a category. Update code below

**_FreelancerLayoutState**

```dart
...
  int? selectedIndex; // Add this
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => selectedIndex = index);
          pushNewScreen(
            context, 
            screen: CategoryPage(category: catList[index])
          );
        },
        child: GridCategory(
          category: catList[index],
          isSelected: selectedIndex == index,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ...
  }
}
```

**GridCategory**

```
class GridCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
  final Category category;
  final bool isSelected; // add this
  // final VoidCallback? press; Remove this
  ...
}
```

**_GridCategoryState**

```
  ...
  // final bool isSelected = false; Remove this
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Removed InkWell
    // return InkWell(
    //   onTap: widget.press,
    //   child: ...
    // );
    return Container(
      width: 110,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.isSelected ? AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor : Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Image.asset(widget.category.catImage!)),
          Text(
            widget.category.iconName!,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  }
  ...
```

Comment: it is changing the color but when I select another category the previous one selected should not be colored.

Comment: In that case you need store a variable like `selectedIndex` in `FreelancerLayout` changes it every time you tap a category. remove local `isSelected`, instead passing from parent like `colored = selectedIndex == index` and a callback to set it 'onTap: selectedIndex = index'

Comment: Ill update comment for your case

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GridCategory` widget to a stateful widget. Then you can update the `onTap` function to change the boolean and then call the callback.

```
onTap: (){
  setState((){
    isSelected = true;
  });
  press();
},
```

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: This will change the colour of each grid category separately.

Comment: I'm facing an error `Undefined name 'isSelected'.`

Comment: please add the code to the stateful widget so I can debug it.

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

On your `GridCategory` widget, pass `isSelected` from parent.

```dart
class GridCategory extends StatelessWidget {
  final Category category;
  final VoidCallback? press;
  final bool isSelected;

  const GridCategory({
    Key? key,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.category,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);
  ......
```

To keep track of selected index you need a list, I am using `List<int>` here,

```dart
class _FreelancerLayoutState extends State<FreelancerLayout>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<FreelancerLayout> {
  List<int> selectedIndex = [];

....

itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
  child: GridCategory(
      isSelected: selectedIndex.contains(index),
      press: () {
        if (selectedIndex.contains(index)) {
          selectedIndex.remove(
              index); // remove selected index if already exist
        } else {
          selectedIndex.add(index);
        }
//... perform others
}),
```

Comment: The color is getting change when I come back from the next screen and after a while the color is getting change.

Comment: I've seen a GitHub issue about `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in past that `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` isnot working properly, I will encourage you to check state management , you can try  putting `selectedIndex` as global for test case but not recommended

Comment: So how can I do this using `getx`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't about getx, you can try provider/riverpod as beginner level.

Comment: The issue about [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin does not work with BottomNavigationBar](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28345)

Comment: look at the tuấn vũ hữu code, it is working but when I press another category the previous one selected should not be colored, how can I resolve it?